# what model to use for placebo controlled trial?

Tags: regression, stata, clinical-trials

First time posting a question, apologizes if I am not doing this correctly.

I have a placebo-controlled, 4-way crossover trial: (1) placebo, (2) drug A, (3) drug B, and (4) combo of drug A and B.
Each patient has a baseline pain score (continuous, 0 to 10) and 4 separate "post-treatment" pain scores, one for each of the 4 regimens.

I would be interested to see if certain baseline characteristics (I can use them as continuous variables or turn them into categorical variables by binning) are associated with the pain response.

At a loss of what statistical setup I would need, would appreciate any insights. (I am reading about mixed effect model but I can't seem to understand how this would apply to my situation).

Thanks,

F

Comment: To what do patients cross over to? Is the endpoint assessed at several points in time? And is the primary endpoint pain reduction by, say, week 12 following a 12 week treatment (with or without cross over).